# illegal characters in path while Deserialise xml?

Tags: c#, xml

I have one xml and i need to deserialize as List. Actually i just used XSD2Code tool to generate the serialize and deserialize methods.

All are working fine but when i pass the filename, i got the xmlstring but not deserialized because **of illegal characters in the path**

My Code :

```
    public  T LoadFromFile(string fileName)
    {
        System.IO.FileStream file = null;
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = null;
        try
        {
            file = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(file);
            string xmlString = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            file.Close();

            return Deserialize(xmlString);
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((file != null))
            {
                file.Dispose();
            }
            if ((sr != null))
            {
                sr.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here i got the xmlString and the string i got is ...

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<ZTIMES_SQL_TO_SAP_CELL.Response xmlns=\"urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions\">\r\n  <IT_RETURN xmlns=\"\">\r\n    <item>\r\n      <INAME>CELLCOMPLETION</INAME>\r\n      <UNQ_ID>1234</UNQ_ID>\r\n      <STATUS>F</STATUS>\r\n    </item>\r\n    <item>\r\n      <INAME>CELLCOMPLETION</INAME>\r\n      <UNQ_ID>1235</UNQ_ID>\r\n      <STATUS>S</STATUS>\r\n    </item>\r\n    <item>\r\n      <INAME>CELLCOMPLETION</INAME>\r\n      <UNQ_ID>1236</UNQ_ID>\r\n      <STATUS>F</STATUS>\r\n    </item>\r\n  </IT_RETURN>\r\n  <IT_CELL_COMP xmlns=\"\">\r\n    <item>\r\n      <UNQ_ID>1234</UNQ_ID>\r\n      <LOC_CODE>LOC1</LOC_CODE>\r\n      <TRSLNO>TRSLNO1</TRSLNO>\r\n      <MODEL>MODEL1</MODEL>\r\n      <CELL>CELL1</CELL>\r\n      <CDATE>1900-01-01</CDATE>\r\n      <COMP_STATUS>COMP_STAT1</COMP_STATUS>\r\n      <NEQUNR>NEQUNR1</NEQUNR>\r\n      <SHIFT>1</SHIFT>\r\n      <ITERATION>1</ITERATION>\r\n      <CREATED_BY>CREATED_BY1</CREATED_BY>\r\n      <CREATED_DT>1900-01-01</CREATED_DT>\r\n      <CREATED_TM>01:01:01</CREATED_TM>\r\n    </item>\r\n    <item>\r\n      <UNQ_ID>1235</UNQ_ID>\r\n      <LOC_CODE>LOC2</LOC_CODE>\r\n      <TRSLNO>TRSLNO2</TRSLNO>\r\n      <MODEL>MODEL2</MODEL>\r\n      <CELL>CELL2</CELL>\r\n      <CDATE>1900-01-01</CDATE>\r\n      <COMP_STATUS>COMP_STAT2</COMP_STATUS>\r\n      <NEQUNR>NEQUNR2</NEQUNR>\r\n      <SHIFT>-79228162514264337593543950335</SHIFT>\r\n      <ITERATION>-79228162514264337593543950335</ITERATION>\r\n      <CREATED_BY>CREATED_BY2</CREATED_BY>\r\n      <CREATED_DT>1900-01-01</CREATED_DT>\r\n      <CREATED_TM>01:01:01</CREATED_TM>\r\n    </item>\r\n    <item>\r\n      <UNQ_ID>1236</UNQ_ID>\r\n      <LOC_CODE>LOC3</LOC_CODE>\r\n      <TRSLNO>TRSLNO3</TRSLNO>\r\n      <MODEL>MODEL3</MODEL>\r\n      <CELL>CELL3</CELL>\r\n      <CDATE>0001-01-01</CDATE>\r\n      <COMP_STATUS>COMP_STAT3</COMP_STATUS>\r\n      <NEQUNR>NEQUNR3</NEQUNR>\r\n      <SHIFT>79228162514264337593543950335</SHIFT>\r\n      <ITERATION>79228162514264337593543950335</ITERATION>\r\n      <CREATED_BY>CREATED_BY3</CREATED_BY>\r\n      <CREATED_DT>1900-01-01</CREATED_DT>\r\n      <CREATED_TM>01:01:01</CREATED_TM>\r\n    </item>\r\n  </IT_CELL_COMP>\r\n</ZTIMES_SQL_TO_SAP_CELL.Response>"
```

My Original xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ZTIMES_SQL_TO_SAP_CELL.Response xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
  <IT_RETURN xmlns="">
    <item>
      <INAME>CELLCOMPLETION</INAME>
      <UNQ_ID>1234</UNQ_ID>
      <STATUS>F</STATUS>
    </item>
    <item>
      <INAME>CELLCOMPLETION</INAME>
      <UNQ_ID>1235</UNQ_ID>
      <STATUS>S</STATUS>
    </item>
    <item>
      <INAME>CELLCOMPLETION</INAME>
      <UNQ_ID>1236</UNQ_ID>
      <STATUS>F</STATUS>
    </item>
  </IT_RETURN>
  <IT_CELL_COMP xmlns="">
    <item>
      <UNQ_ID>1234</UNQ_ID>
      <LOC_CODE>LOC1</LOC_CODE>
      <TRSLNO>TRSLNO1</TRSLNO>
      <MODEL>MODEL1</MODEL>
      <CELL>CELL1</CELL>
      <CDATE>1900-01-01</CDATE>
      <COMP_STATUS>COMP_STAT1</COMP_STATUS>
      <NEQUNR>NEQUNR1</NEQUNR>
      <SHIFT>1</SHIFT>
      <ITERATION>1</ITERATION>
      <CREATED_BY>CREATED_BY1</CREATED_BY>
      <CREATED_DT>1900-01-01</CREATED_DT>
      <CREATED_TM>01:01:01</CREATED_TM>
    </item>
    <item>
      <UNQ_ID>1235</UNQ_ID>
      <LOC_CODE>LOC2</LOC_CODE>
      <TRSLNO>TRSLNO2</TRSLNO>
      <MODEL>MODEL2</MODEL>
      <CELL>CELL2</CELL>
      <CDATE>1900-01-01</CDATE>
      <COMP_STATUS>COMP_STAT2</COMP_STATUS>
      <NEQUNR>NEQUNR2</NEQUNR>
      <SHIFT>-79228162514264337593543950335</SHIFT>
      <ITERATION>-79228162514264337593543950335</ITERATION>
      <CREATED_BY>CREATED_BY2</CREATED_BY>
      <CREATED_DT>1900-01-01</CREATED_DT>
      <CREATED_TM>01:01:01</CREATED_TM>
    </item>
    <item>
      <UNQ_ID>1236</UNQ_ID>
      <LOC_CODE>LOC3</LOC_CODE>
      <TRSLNO>TRSLNO3</TRSLNO>
      <MODEL>MODEL3</MODEL>
      <CELL>CELL3</CELL>
      <CDATE>0001-01-01</CDATE>
      <COMP_STATUS>COMP_STAT3</COMP_STATUS>
      <NEQUNR>NEQUNR3</NEQUNR>
      <SHIFT>79228162514264337593543950335</SHIFT>
      <ITERATION>79228162514264337593543950335</ITERATION>
      <CREATED_BY>CREATED_BY3</CREATED_BY>
      <CREATED_DT>1900-01-01</CREATED_DT>
      <CREATED_TM>01:01:01</CREATED_TM>
    </item>
  </IT_CELL_COMP>
</ZTIMES_SQL_TO_SAP_CELL.Response>
```

please help me to identy the error

Update:
  Added Deserialize Method

```
public  T Deserialize(string xml)
{
   // System.IO.StringReader stringReader = null;
    StreamReader stream = null;
    try
    {
        Serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        stream = new StreamReader(xml);

       // stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xml);
        return ((T)(Serializer.Deserialize(System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stream))));
    }
    finally
    {
        if ((stream != null))
        {
            stream.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what does your Deserialize method look like? Note that your code is a longwinded way of writing `File.ReadAllText(fileName)` - and that you should use `using` statements to avoid all that manual disposal. You also don't need as many brackets in your `if` conditions.

Comment: I removed all the code and add simply string xmlString = File.ReadAllText(fileName); But still i got the same error.

Comment: Well yes, you would. That's my point - that's a much simpler way of doing the same thing. But the problem is presumably in your `Deserialize` method, which you haven't shown us.

Comment: i have added Deserialize method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right, now we've got your `Deserialize` method, the problem is obvious:

```
stream = new StreamReader(xml);
```

That's treating `xml` as a filename, not as XML. Either you should just have:

```
public T Deserialize(string filename)
{
    // There's no need to make the serializer a property or instance variable...
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        return (T) serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

... *or* make it take XML, and use a `StringReader`:

```
public T Deserialize(string xml)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    return (T) serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
}
```

Personally I prefer the former version - it allows the XML parsing code to automatically detect encodings, whereas currently you're *assuming* UTF-8 when you read the file as a string.

Comment: `StringReader` implementes `IDisposable`, so you should release the instance.

Comment: @Gene: No, there's no need in this case - it only implements `IDisposable` because `TextReader` does. There are no unmanaged resources to release. It wouldn't do any execution-time *harm* to add a `using` statement, but the code would be more long-winded for no benefit.

Comment: Thanks friend. I got confused with other logic.